# Windows creates pagefile.sys on newly added drive

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, pagefile

Windows 7 x64

HDD 1 SATA multiple partition including windows in C:\

HDD 2 IDE (I added this drive later to the system)
partitions-1 primary
partition-2 logical

windows page file: system managed

since ide appears as Disk 0 in diskmgmt and first partition on this drive is also primary in addition to SATA c:\ primary I think IDE takes priority and my system creates a pagefile.sys on this IDE drive partition-1

When I remove my HDD 2, pagefile is created on HDD 1 SATA as it should be.

I wish to keep page file as system managed and stop the IDE drive creating a pagefile.sys on it. Because this IDE is less capacity drive and pagefile.sys taking lot of space unwantedly on it.

is there a way. should I make IDE HDD all partitions logical or any other way possible?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to let the system to fully manage the page file(s), then you have to let it do what it wants.

Otherwise:

Uncheck "*Automatically manage paging file size for all drives*" and instead pick (just) the drive you want a system managed page file on, and set it to "*System managed size*".

Then select the drive(s) you don't want a page file on and set it to "*No paging file*".

[image: Windows 7 Virtual Memory dialog]

Comment: Thanks for reply, I changed the partition type on HDD2 partition-1 from 'primary' to logical from direct boot utility. but with system managed, same partition gets pagefile.sys . reason is that my RAM is 6GB and this HDD2 partition is the only one having more than 6GB space free, all partitions free space on HDD 1 have are far less than 6GB available. anyways I think that's the way to go you told. either system managed or set manually and exclude he required partition.